# Error con pd.DataFrame.replace, no puede convertir cadena unicode a float

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, diccionarios, unicode

Estoy tratando de multiplicar un marco de datos por referencia por lo tanto estoy usando un diccionario para poder multiplicarlo. Cuando trato de llenar mi diccionario de los valores en las filas de Excel no puedo convertir los valores a float ya que son unicode. Estoy usando Python 2.7.10, ¿Alguien me puede decir alguna manera eficiente de poder convertir de unicode a float?

```
import pandas as pd
#convertir el archivo de excel en un marco de datos
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Pedro/Desktop/dataframe.xls")

#llenar el diccionario con las llaves y sus valores. este sera el marcos df2
d = {"M1-4":0.60,"M1-5/R10":0.85,"C5-3":0.85,"M1-5/R7-3":0.85,"M1-4/R7A":0.85,"R7A":0.85,"M1-4/R6A":0.85,"M1-4/R6B":0.85,"R6A":0.85,"PARK":0.20,"M1-6/R10":0.85,"R6B":0.85,"R9":0.85,"M1-5/R9":0.85}

#Convertir el diccionario en archivo de Excel
df5 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
df5.to_excel('bob_dict.xlsx')

#llenar el diccionario con un archivo de excel
df2 = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Pedro/Desktop/bob_dict.xlsx")
#Convertir el marco de datos a un diccionario.
dictionary = df2.to_dict(orient='dict')
#multiplicar el diccionario como referencia.

b = df.filter(like ='Value').values
c = df.filter(like ='ZONE').replace(dictionary).astype(float).values

df['pro_cum'] = ((c * b).sum(axis =1))
```

cuando ejecuto el código me da el error:

> ValueError: no se pudo convertir RAB string a un float.

Este es el marco con el cual trabajo `df`:

```
HP    ZONE           Value  ZONE1       Value1
3     R7A           0.7009  M1-4/R6B    0.00128
2     R6A           0.5842  M1-4/R7A    0.00009
7     M1-6/R10      0.1909  M1-4/R6A    0.73576
9     R6B           0.6919  PARK        0.03459
6     PARK          1.0400  M1-4/R6A    0.33002
9.3   M1-4/R6A      0.7878  PARK        0.59700
10.6  M1-4/R6B      0.0291  R6A         0.29621
11.9  R9            0.0084  M1-4        0.00058
13.2  M1-5/R10      0.0049  M1-4        0.65568
14.5  M1-4/R7A      0.0050  C5-3        0.00096
15.8  M1-5/R7-3     0.0189  C5-3        1.59327
17.1  M1-5/R9       0.3296  M1-4/R6B    0.43918
18.4  C5-3          0.5126  R6B         0.20835
19.7  M1-4          0.5126  PARK        0.22404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando creas `df5` a partir del diccionario, al pasar `'index`' al argumento `orient`, se crea el DataFrame con las claves como índice y los valores quedan como columna (o columnas si la clave es un iterable, como una lista). Si no indicas el nombre de las columnas con el argumento `columns` (a partir de Pandas 0.23.0) te las nombra automáticamente como un entero empezando en 0:

```
              0
M1-4       0.60
M1-5/R10   0.85
C5-3       0.85
M1-5/R7-3  0.85
M1-4/R7A   0.85
R7A        0.85
M1-4/R6A   0.85
M1-4/R6B   0.85
R6A        0.85
PARK       0.20
M1-6/R10   0.85
R6B        0.85
R9         0.85
M1-5/R9    0.85
```

Cuando traes de vuelta el DataFrame y lo vuelves a pasar a un diccionario mediante `dictionary = df2.to_dict(orient='dict')` s**e crea un diccionario de diccionarios**, en el que la clave es el nombre de la columna y los valores un diccionario con las parejas `indice: valor para esa columna`:

```
{0: {'M1-4': 0.6, 'M1-5/R10': 0.85, 'C5-3': 0.85,
     'M1-5/R7-3': 0.85, 'M1-4/R7A': 0.85, 'R7A': 0.85,
     'M1-4/R6A': 0.85, 'M1-4/R6B': 0.85, 'R6A': 0.85,
     'PARK': 0.2, 'M1-6/R10': 0.85, 'R6B': 0.85,
     'R9': 0.85, 'M1-5/R9': 0.85
     }
    }
```

Cuando a `pandas.DataFrame.replace` se le pasa un diccionario de este tipo lo que hace es buscar la columna apropiada (0) del DataFrame (`df`), a continuación mira si cada índice está en el diccionario anidado asociado a esa columna y si lo está reemplaza el valor.

Como la única clave del diccionario es 0 y esa columna no existe en `df`, `replace` no sustituye nada, quedando las columnas `ZONEx` como estaban, conteniendo cadenas ("R7A", "M1-4/R6A", etc) que no se pueden lógicamente convertir en floats.

Por lo tanto puedes simplemente seleccionar la clave `0` de `dictionary`:

```
dictionary = df2.to_dict()
c = df.filter(like='ZONE').replace(dictionary[0]).astype(float).values
```

o también usar `pandas.Series.to_dict` sobre la columna:

```
dictionary = df2[0].to_dict()
c = df.filter(like='ZONE').replace(dictionary).astype(float).values
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que si el valor de una de las columnas no se encuentra en el diccionario tendremos el mismo error.

Comment: Gracias por la clarificacion esto resolvio mi error.